# Как можно еще построить такой график?

Tags: javascript, массивы, графика, диаграммы, google-chart

Как можно еще построить такой график не используя в массиве эти странные NULL? Вот [Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/uw38w8Lt/1/)

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['дата', 'онлайн', 'офлайн'],
      ['09.05.16',  55,      null],
      ['10.05.16',  44,      null],
      ['11.05.16',  7,      null],
      ['12.05.16',  56,      null],
      ['13.05.16',  45,      null],
      ['14.05.16',  45,      null],
      ['15.05.16',  60,      60],
      ['16.05.16',  60,      60],
      ['17.05.16',  34,      null],
      ['18.05.16',  43,      null],
      ['19.05.16',  60,      60],
      ['20.05.16',  60,      60],
      ['21.05.16',  55,      null]
    ]);
    var options = {
      title: 'Как можно еще построить такой график не используя в массиве эти странные NULL?',
      hAxis: {title: 'Дата',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Comment: чем они странные?

Comment: @Павел Хотелось бы передавать что то такое:       `['15.05.16',  null],
      ['16.05.16',  null],
      ['17.05.16',  34],
      ['18.05.16',  43],
      ['19.05.16',  null],
      ['20.05.16',  null],
      ['21.05.16',  55]`

Comment: @wwwplaton, залог прекрасного взаимопонимания это объяснение простыми словами того, чего вы хотите получить, у вас есть только пример какого-то кода, без понимания сути вопроса.

Comment: @MasterAlex посмотрите на ответ ниже, там просто линия. Если в данных передать `NULL` то линии нет, а она мне нужна красным цветом там

Comment: @wwwplaton, ну если ответ ниже именно то что вы хотели, то можно ничего не объяснять остальным :)

Comment: @MasterAlex не совсем так, у меня данные выводят вот так https://jsfiddle.net/o3zy8ox5/ если `NULL` то линии нет, а мне она нужна и подсветить красным цветом.

Answer (score 1):

Вот [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/) от google charts думаю это то что вам нужно.

```
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBackgroundColor);

function drawBackgroundColor() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

      data.addRows([
        [0, 0],   [1, 10],  [2, 23],  [3, 17],  [4, 18],  [5, 9],
        [6, 11],  [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35],
        [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
        [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42], [21, 55], [22, 56], [23, 57],
        [24, 60], [25, 50], [26, 52], [27, 51], [28, 49], [29, 53],
        [30, 55], [31, 60], [32, 61], [33, 59], [34, 62], [35, 65],
        [36, 62], [37, 58], [38, 55], [39, 61], [40, 64], [41, 65],
        [42, 63], [43, 66], [44, 67], [45, 69], [46, 69], [47, 70],
        [48, 72], [49, 68], [50, 66], [51, 65], [52, 67], [53, 70],
        [54, 71], [55, 72], [56, 73], [57, 75], [58, 70], [59, 68],
        [60, 64], [61, 60], [62, 65], [63, 67], [64, 68], [65, 69],
        [66, 70], [67, 72], [68, 75], [69, 80]
      ]);

      var options = {
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Popularity'
        },
        backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Comment: Если null то как подсветить линию?